# How to point to child elements when vue-tour is initialised in parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <q-card id="scrollBody" class="detail-page-wrap" @scroll="handleScroll">
      <childComponent />
      </q-card>
</div>
</template>
```

Need to point to child component elements, so need to add targets but they aren't coming when static ids are added to parent component and when the tour is instantiated on the parent mount.